# Cannot assign to read only property (value) of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript

I have a function which retrieves an object.

```
  const removeLogo = (values: any) => {
   values.settings.logoUrl = undefined;
  setMaster({ ...values });
  };
```

my object is the following :

```
 values = {
  name: "test",
  reference: "ref"
  settings: {
  logoUrl : 'url'
 }
}
```

in this object I simply want to change a value :

```
values.settings.logoUrl = undefined;
```

but I end up with a following error message :

```
 form-mail-reminders.tsx:83 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 
 'logoUrl' of object '#<Object>'
```

Is there a solution to modify the value of the object without having this error message ?

Comment: Make the property writable

Comment: @Andreas Properties are writable by default. You have to go out of your way to make a property read-only.

Comment: If this object is coming from a library, you should check its documentation to find the correct way to update it. There's probably a method for this.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I know that... o.O But as you can see on the error message that property is read-only - for whatever reason... Hence my close vote because this is definitely not a [mcve] and therefor lacks relevant information

Comment: @Andreas It's almost certainly not an object they defined, so they can't change it.

Comment: @Barmer _"Hence my close vote because this is definitely not a [mcve] and therefor lacks relevant information"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the property of the objects to writeable as they are set to non writeable.

> **writable**
>
> true if and only if the value associated with the property
> may be changed with an assignment operator. Defaults to false.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties

And for you:

```
Object.defineProperty(values, 'logoUrl', {
   writable:true
});
```

Comment: That's only the case if you define a property with `Object.defineProperty()`. And there's no such call of `.defineProperty()` in OPs question/script.